# How to mix server-side Jax-rs call with native files without prefix?

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

We are currently using a Jersey JAX-RS implementation to handle our REST requests (server-side Jersey). Our web.xml file is configured so all /rest/* requests are handled by Jersey. That's fine. Our server is currently Tomcat6, and using Java6 ( on Ubuntu 11.04 )

So, ://myserver/rest/customer/ is ok and Jersey calls the class with @Path("/customer") prefix.

Now we also have static content, for example ://myserver/images/... wich loads fine.

Is there a way to do so that we can get rid of the /rest/* prefix and mix it all together?

What we want to achieve : 
://myserver/rest/customer/ → Jersey
://myserver/rest/images/ → the native image Directory of the war

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy to achieve. Just register Jersey ServletContainer in web.xml as a filter (instead of servlet) - see the bottom of [this page](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/package-summary.html) for an example - and either use [ServletContainer.PROPERTY_WEB_PAGE_CONTENT_REGEX](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer.html#PROPERTY_WEB_PAGE_CONTENT_REGEX) or [ServletContainer.FEATURE_FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer.html#FEATURE_FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404) init param to make the static content accessible.

Comment: Perfect ! thank you. I agree too with other option, but find this one more suitable. ServletContainer.FEATURE_FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404 is a well hidden option :)

Answer (score 0):

First, when it comes to servlet mapping, priority goes like this:

1. Path mapping: `/rest/*`
2. Extension mapping: `*.png`
3. Default: `/`

### Path mapping + extension mapping: bad idea

So you can't map static resources by their file extension within an existing path mapping (that would be a bad idea anyway, managing all static file extensions in your web.xml).

Path mapping's priority > ext mapping.

### Using a filter

Set up an UrlRewriteFilter in your `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And in your `urlrewrite.xml` configuration file:

```
<urlrewrite default-match-type="wildcard">
    <rule>
        <from>/rest/images/**</from>
        <to>/images/$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

### Not mapping static resources in /rest

This may not suit your needs, but this is my favorite!
Mapping static resources within `/rest` says *"Hey, developer, come GET/POST/PUT/DELETE thoses static resources, it's okay"*:

- If you can't GET/PUT/POST/DELETE those resources, then you shouldn't map them in `/rest`. It gives the wrong impression.
- If ou actually want to manipulate those resources through a REST webservice, then let Jersey do the heavy lifting and serve those resources (check out the [jersey-samples](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/samples/jersey-samples/) for an example).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In fact, it's just the contrary we try to achieve. We want to limit Jersey to some special things ( /employees, /customers... ) and let static files ( /images, /dojo, /javascript ) be handled by Tomcat natively. The problem is, for SEO and URL beauty, we'd like to avoid using /rest/employees, /rest/customers.
This is this type of mixin we want to achieve.