# Precedence of filter over servlet in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, jersey, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have Apache Tomcat Version 7.0.26 running.

A have a JAX-RS servlet under /test, which calls jsps which in tourn should be handled by the Tomcat servlet engine.

E.g.,
`/test` should be handled by jersey, but `/test/result.jsp` should be handled by the JSP engine.

I don't want the user to see different urls, therefore, I rewrite the jsp URLs to /jsp internally.

Config is like that:

[UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) (in `urlrewrite.xml`):

```
<rule>
    <from>^/([^j][^s][^p].*\.jsp)</from>
    <to>/jsp/$1</to>
</rule>
```

`web.xml`:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
   <!-- set the amount of seconds the conf file will be checked for reload
   can be a valid integer (0 denotes check every time,
      empty/not set denotes no reload check) -->
   <init-param>
     <param-name>confReloadCheckInterval</param-name>
     <param-value>0</param-value>
   </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>test</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

A call to `/xyz.jsp` is redirected to `/jsp/xyz.jsp`. A call to `/test/xyz.jsp` leads to `404 - Servlet Test is not available`. I thought that filters have precedence over servlets, don't they?

I am aware of the related question [Servlet vs Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957165/servlet-vs-filter), but they don't state anything about the precedence.

BTW: [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) seems to be similar to UrlRewriteFilter, but I haven't tried it yet. I (currently) like UrlRewriteFilter more.

EDIT: The question [How to mix server-side Jax-rs call with native files without prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210546/how-to-mix-server-side-jax-rs-call-with-native-files-without-prefix) asks the question behind my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can make it work quite easily and you don't need any url rewriting. Just place your jsp's into test/ dir, register Jersey as a servlet filter instead of a servlet (i.e. replace all occurrences of *servlet* with *filter* in your web.xml) and add com.sun.jersey.config.feature.FilterForwardOn404 init param set to true. The resulting web.xml should look as follows:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Test</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>test</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.FilterForwardOn404</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Test</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Works great. One has to pay attention to adapt the `@PATH` directive of each Jersey filter.

Comment: Meanwhile, I return a Viewable with the jsp file as parameter. I also turned off FilterForwardOn404, because with normal code a 404 created by the code also leads to a forward, which is not always desirable (depending on the setup).

Comment: Can a base url be specified using filter-mapping?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that such a setup does not work. Placing all rest services unter `/rest` and all jsps under `/jsp` does the trick.